# How to connect react-three-fiber to mobx

Tags: mobx, react-three-fiber

How to hook up react-three-fiber to mobx?

I have this component. How do I hook it up?

```
export default function Player(props) {
    const mesh = useRef()

    useFrame((a) => {

    });

    return (
        <mesh>
            <boxBufferGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color={'orange'} />
        </mesh>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping it with `observer`?
If that doesn't work, you can use a local state and set it through a `reaction` callback.